# libGDX on SBT: roboVM backend is referencing the wrong ASM version

Tags: scala, libgdx, robovm

When trying to compile my Game with roboVM, I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.robovm.compiler.plugin.objc.ObjCProtocolProxyPlugin$1 has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

I have investigated some many hours, coming to the conclusion that it has to do with the ASM library: In the library ASM, up to version 3.3.2, the class ClassVisitor was an interface. It got promoted to an abstract class in 4.0 and the robovm backend bytecode uses a >= 4.0 version while my SBT builder tries to use a version < 4.0.

The roboVM code in question can be found here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/blob/master/compiler/src/main/java/org/robovm/compiler/plugin/objc/ObjCProtocolProxyPlugin.java#L145

Now, while I realize that this is the issue, I have no idea how to fix / work around it. I do not want to compile libGDX from source...

To setup my app I used existing templates, namely this one: https://github.com/ajhager/libgdx-sbt-project.g8. Also, I use the latest versions respectively:

```
sbt 0.13.5
libGDX 1.4.1
scala 2.11.3
roboVM 1.0.0-alpha-04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now when I investigated further, searching for the culprit in this conglomerate, I found that indeed two 'asm's were included in the classpath, the one with version 3.3.1 being mentioned earlier:

`scalac -classpath ...:~/.ivy2/cache/asm/asm-all/jars/asm-all-3.3.1.jar:...:~/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-all/jars/asm-all-4.2.jar:...`

This obviously caused the crash. Now I only had to find the place where 3.3.1 was set as dependency and I was rather quick in finding it, at long last: pfn/android-sdk-plugin. For whatever reason, they set this as a dependency (albeit somehow not using it in their code). There were evidently no conflicts since the group ids differed: asm:asm-all:3.3.1 vs org.ow2.asm-all:4.2.

This is easily the dumbest thing I have ever walked across and I'm grinding my teeth that it took so long and so much debugging to get behind it. Hmpf!

I fixed it by cloning the android-sdk-plugin repository and adjusting the ASM version / group id to 4.2. I then continued to `sbt publish-local` and increased the version number dependency in my project to fit the cloned SNAPSHOT version's.

I hope this will help anyone that stumbles across this behaviour.

So long,
Danyel.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure you saved me many hours. You should accept your own answer.